# Left a comment on my own question, will the user get notified?

Tags: discussion, comments, questions, notifications

Someone edited a question of mine, and I asked that person a question by leaving a comment on my question.  However, when I typed @username_of_editor, I noticed SE did not offer the username autofill that it normally does, so I suspect the user will not get a notification of my comment.  In addition, I noticed my question did not jump to the top of the active list after I left the comment, so that user may not realize I have left a comment for him.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Editors can be notified but their names are not available for auto-completion; it'd take too much resources to have to query the database for those names.

If you matched their name (even partially) editors will be notified, yes.

Quoting from [How do comment @replies work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43019/how-do-comment-replies-work)

> - Tab name completion can be used, and that knows when @name is unnecessary and will then not automatically complete names. **It also does not work for editors**.
>
> [...]
>
> - Notifications apply to the author, users with active bounties, commenters (associated to current non-deleted comments), **and editors of the question or answer** that you are commenting on—users not in that list cannot be notified. [...]

Emphasis mine.

Comment: Want to clarify why you said an editor *can* be notified.  *Will* the editor be notified if you do an @editor?

Comment: @pacoverflow: yes, they will be notified.

Comment: Thanks, I hope it still works considering he has a space in his username.  I did an @Firstname Lastname

Comment: @pacoverflow: see the referenced FAQ; it'll work but the correct full version is to use no spaces; `@FirstnameLastname`.